# Xcode 8 doesn't seem to be honoring my target platform when building

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode8

I can't tell if this is my configuration issue (likely) or Xcode 8's bug (also likely).

I'm working on porting an iOS framework, [HLSpriteKit](https://github.com/hilogames/HLSpriteKit) over to Mac. Because there's a couple of iOS-specific files in the project, and now one specific to Mac, I chose to create two separate targets, one for iOS and one for macOS.

[image]

For the shared code, I want to use `#if TARGET_OS_OSX` to target macOS and `#else` for everything else:

[image]

When I try to build this using my iOS target, it works great. But when I try to build with the Mac target (as you can see in the upper left of the screenshot), it fails. It seems to be failing the `#if TARGET_OS_OSX` check even though I'm building for Mac. Better yet, when I cmd-click `TARGET_OS_OSX`, it takes me to the macOS 10.12 TargetConditionals.h file with the line `#define TARGET_OS_OSX 1`. So why is it failing?

My questions:

1. What controls which TargetConditionals.h file (ie: iOS or macOS) Xcode chooses when compiling? I was under the assumption it was purely based on which device I've selected in the Scheme/Device picker, and the list of devices available is based on **Build Settings -> Supported Platforms** for the given target. Right?
2. Is Xcode building my project differently than the text editor auto-complete (ie: the cmd-click support) is leading me to believe?
3. Should I be doing this a different way?

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work because TARGET_OS_OSX is defined for iOS as well.

try user defined MACRO or use following.

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
   // iOS code here
#else
   // OS X code here
#endif
```

Comment: It **is** defined, but I'm not using ```#ifdef```. I'm using ```#if``` to evaluate whether it's true or false. Also, you're likely thinking of ```TARGET_OS_MAC``` which is both defined and TRUE on both Mac and iOS, but ```TARGET_OS_OSX``` is different.

Comment: Sorry, I misread on TARGET_OS_*. Any reason you don't want to use TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR ?

Comment: At least in my case, iPhone, AppleTV, Apple watch, and corresponding simulators all use the same code. Mac is the only difference. But apart from all that, it still doesn't fix the issue because the problem is not which constant I'm choosing -- it's which header file is being chosen to define those constants.

Comment: also, dont forget #include <TargetConditionals.h> // required in Xcode 8+